# IIS 10 site needing URL Rewrite for changed WordPress subfolder name

Tags: wordpress, iis, url-rewriting

I have a client with an ASP.NET MVC project running on IIS 10.

In IIS 10 I have an Application setup under the site that points to a WordPress installation folder. The alias was previously `oldblog` and has now changed to `blog`.

The WordPress URI was requested to be changed so I need to permanently redirect requests to the old URI to the new one.

Root ASP site: https://www.example.com/

Old WP URI: https://www.example.com/oldblog/

New WP URI: https://www.example.com/blog/

The following rule only partially works. `oldblog` does get rewritten to `blog`, but the rest of the URI is unpredictable/inconsistent.

```
  <rule name="Rewrite /oldblog to /blog" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^oldblog(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/blog/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
```

I need to rewrite all requests to /oldblog/* to /blog/* - regardless of the full URI/querystring, I only want to rewrite `oldblog` to `blog`

```
/oldblog/  =>  /blog/
/oldblog/category/somecategory/  =>  /blog/category/somecategory/
```

Comment: You should see into those inconsistent cases via FRT, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules and also use privacy tab of a browser to test.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try to make tests with the URL Rewrite rule below could help you redirect from URLs below.

```
/oldblog/  =>  /blog/
/oldblog/category/somecategory/  =>  /blog/category/somecategory/
```

**Sample Rule**

```
<rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
            <rule name="Rule-3" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
                                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="/oldblog(.*)|/oldblog" />
                            </conditions>
                            <action type="Redirect" url="/blog{C:1}" />
                    </rule>
            </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**Test Result**

[image]

Further, you could modify the rule above as per your own requirements.